# Transform InternetExplorer to XML

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I just discovered `xml` or `xmlhttp` and this is entirely new to me.
I am trying to create a macro wherein it would go through all the list of websites in column J starting at row 2 (header at row 1). Get the information that I want from each website, then display them in column K, which is right next to the websites where the information was taken from.

Column J has a list of websites, starting at J2. Let's say it would go all the way down to J10. From each website, there is a certain information I want to get, so the macro will visit the website at J2, get that information and paste it in K2, then visit the website in J3, paste that information in K3, and so on. I already have an existing list of website at column J, which also happens to be dynamic.

This is the current code that I have using IE that I want to convert into xml/xmlhttp.

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim sdd As String
    Dim add As Variant
    Dim html As Object
    Dim mylinks As Object
    Dim mylink As Object
    Dim result As String

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, "J").Value

    ' Hide InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    ie.navigate myURL

    ' Loop until page fully loads
    Do While ie.readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    ' Information i want to get from the URLs
    sdd = ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("timeline-text")(0).innerText

    ' Format the result
    add = Split(sdd, "$")
    Range("K3") = add(1)

    ' Close InternetExplorer
    ie.Quit

    'Return to Normal?
    ie.Visible = True
    End
    Next
    ' Clean up
    Set ie = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

I am trying to get the "85100", not the $85,100

```
<span class="font-size-base font-normal">Est.</span>
<span itemprop="price" content="85100">
$85,100
</span>
```

I'm hoping you could help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "I am trying to get the "85100", not the $85,100" you mean to get the value associated with the content attribute in your example or what is inside the span tags?

Comment: Hi Dan, I have a lot friends whose name is Dan :)
 And yes, I want whats inside the content attribute. I think `Html.querySelector("span[itemprop='price']").getAttribute("content")` is able to do that. I just need to make the macro run through the list and paste the resulting information to the next column

Answer (score 0):

I would structure something like as follows, where the IE object is created outside the loop. You use css selectors throughout. You may need a timed loop to ensure element is present on page. Use a proper page load wait as shown.

Use an explicit worksheet name to put the worksheet in a variable to work with.

You might want to add a test that myURL has http/https in it as you may have blank cells in range and only want to work with likely urls values.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As Object, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim myURL As String, sdd As String, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' <change as required  
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    With ie
        .Visible = False

        For i = 2 To lastrow

            myURL = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value

            .navigate2 myURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            sdd = .document.querySelector(".price").getAttribute("content")
            ws.Cells(i, "K") = sdd

        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    'Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

---

**With a timed loop:**

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As Object, lastrow As Long, i As Long, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Dim myURL As String, sdd As String, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' <change as required
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    With ie
        .Visible = False

        For i = 2 To lastrow

            myURL = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value

            .Navigate2 myURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = HTMLDoc.querySelector(".price")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing

            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                sdd = ele.getAttribute("content")
                ws.Cells(i, "K") = sdd
            End If

        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    'Application.StatusBar = vbnullstring
End Sub
```